# Is there a word meaning "to support something as if you are waving flags for it"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a word meaning "to support something as if you are waving flags for it"?

I remember I may have encountered a word "flagwave" somewhere, in a sentence looking like "*Do not flagwave for a technology*". But I could not find this word in dictionaries, and only found this usage in [one piece of news](https://www.thenationalnews.com/arts-culture/books/a-review-of-the-man-booker-prize-short-and-longlists-1.667768):

> *The Guardian*’s appraisal of Emily Fridlund’s contender, *History Of Wolves*, was simply “strikingly impotent’. *The New York Times*, which you would expect to **flagwave for** virtuoso American writer George Saunders, moaned that *Lincoln in the Bardo* – by some distance the Man Booker favourite – would have “benefited immensely from some judicious pruning”.

So generally, I'm looking for a word meaning "to support something as if you are waving flags for it" that can be used as in "[?] for an ideology" or "[?] for our team" (this can be literally waving flags).

---

Additionally, if I say "to flagwave for *sth*", will native speakers get the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for something like _espouse_.

Comment: "To flagwave" is metaphorical and it seems to be a neologism. In the meaning of *to support something as if you are waving flags for it*, it is a niche verb - the whole clause is something that, in standard English, would be said very infrequently and thus is best described in a phrase or clause. I suppose "**celebrate**" would come close to "flagwave"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***cheer***

> to give a loud shout of approval or encouragement:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cheer)

Think of ***cheerleaders***, waving their pom-poms at the home team audience.

[image]

[Here](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/23/us/trump-cheerleaders-north-carolina.html) we see North Carolina cheerleaders chanting and spelling out  spelling out "TRUMP".

So we could say

"The New York Times, which you would expect to ***cheerlead*** for virtuoso American writer George Saunders..."

> to urge on or encourage especially by shouts

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheer)

Comment: Thanks! I think the closest choice is *to cheerlead*.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you'll get no closer than **champion.**

It's perhaps rather old-fashioned, but that perhaps hints at the days of chivalry, with all the pennants flying. I'll give Merriam-Webster's relevant definitions of the more common noun first:

> *champion* ...
>
> 2: a militant advocate or defender
>
> - *a champion of civil rights*
>
> 3: WARRIOR, FIGHTER
>
> - *a champion of his king*
>
> 4: one that does battle for another's rights or honor
>
> - *God will raise me up a champion* — Sir Walter Scott; *Ivanhoe*

which inform the senses of the verb

> *champion* [transitive verb]
>
> 1: to act as militant supporter of : UPHOLD, ADVOCATE
>
> - *always champions the cause of the underdog*
>
> 2: to protect or fight for as a champion
>
> - *championed the ladies chivalrously in the tilts*

Answer (score 1):

What immediately comes to mind for me is the word *semaphore* used metaphorically in the verb form.

> Semaphore is a system of sending messages by using two flags. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/semaphore))

> an apparatus for visual signaling (as by the position of one or more movable arms) ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semaphore))

> to signal by semaphore ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/semaphore))

Used metaphorically, it may get you what you need.

Using your example: "The New York Times, which you would expect to *semaphore* for virtuoso American writer George Saunders"

Another example: "He semaphored every emotion, belting love songs with outspread arms or pounding his hand on his heart."

For other such examples see [here](https://www.google.com/search?lr=&safe=active&as_qdr=all&sxsrf=ALeKk00m-apzgJVFzOrb3mIoR_pw5KFJGQ:1606579517249&q=semaphored%20site:www.nytimes.com&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim5LaLz6XtAhUGCjQIHZyjAzYQvgUoAXoECAsQMQ&biw=2636&bih=1436).

Comment: Good point, but I think *semaphore* has more a meaning of "informing" instead of "strongly supporting". Moreover when I think of "waving flags to support", I actually will imagine [a really large flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Madrid_may_day375.jpg) instead of [two small ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:US_Navy_051129-N-0685C-007_Quartermaster_Seaman_Ryan_Ruona_signals_with_semaphore_flags_during_a_replenishment_at_sea.jpg), which is implied by *semaphore*.

Comment: @H.Rhen I would immediately think of the information transmission meaning of "semaphore" - the notion that it was intended to describe cheering for something would never occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but could you be thinking of *unflagging*?

> If you describe something such as support, effort, or enthusiasm as unflagging, you mean that it does not stop or get less as time passes. ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/unflagging))

> not changing or becoming weaker. *His unflagging enthusiasm was an inspiration for all of us.* ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/unflagging))

> showing no signs of weariness even after long hard effort ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unflagging))

[Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unflagging) gives this example:

> "being rewarded for the *unflagging* zeal with which she led the fund-raising campaign"